# How to set drools to breadth first?

Tags: drools

I am moving my CLIPS application to Drools. It requires rule engine fires breadth first. I discovered that Drools 7.4.1 is depth first. I don't see in Drools documentation any mention on how to make it breadth first. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The terms "depth first" and "breadth first" do not apply to the rue firing order of Drools. There are some rule attributes for influencing this order but it is generally a bad strategy to base an application on some specific order of the evaluation of rule logic.

Comment: Equivalently, First in First out (FIFO) is what I need. My application is a natural FIFO problem. Drool document says Drool default to LIFO. It seems to indicate can be configured to FIFO. But I cannot find how to do that in the 7.4.1 document. CLIPS allows user to set "Breadth First" or "Depth First". I am surprised that Drools does not give user a choice.

Comment: Neither "depth first" and "breadth first" nor "FIFO" and "LIFO" make any sense in logic programming. Facts are facts are facts - and if a recent fact (Weather: it's raining) supersedes  and older one (Weather: sunshine) it is the task of the rule author to remove an older Weather as soon as a younger one arrives. - You may have a problem where a RBS may not provide the best way to a solution.

Comment: My application needs consideration of number of steps away from initial conditions. In the last in first out mode, one path may be progressed very far while other conditions have not used yet. My app cares about the global behavior of inference. I can implement a "generation" value, but that's an added complexity unnecessary if we have FIFO.

Comment: Do you mean "forward chaining" and "backward chaining"? If so, check the Drools documentation - there is a certain support for backward chaining, but not as comprehensive as in Prolog.